# Sliding divs from left and right simultaneously

Tags: jquery, overlay, slide

I came across this website with a really cool effect when clicking on the works displayed 2 overlay 'divs' with information slide from the left and right and meet 'in the middle' of the screen.

Any ideas on how this can be recreated? 
Here's the site: http://www.helloimcody.com

Comment: why did this get voted down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite simply done. I'll just focus on the right div but the same applies to both, just with different names and values. The CSS of that right container is as follows:

```
#info-container {
  z-index: 5000;
  position: absolute;    /* important */
  top: 0px;
  right: -2000px;        /* important */
  width: 280px;
  padding: 75px;
  background: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
```

As you may assume, the right container has the *id* of *info-container*. When you click on a link on the page to open the info, after the script has added content to the container, the class of *info-in* is applied. Then in the stylesheet:

```
.info-in {
  right: 0px !important;
  transition: ease .47s all .83s;
  -webkit-transition: ease .47s all .83s;
  -moz-transition: ease .47s all .83s;
}
```

*(note that a similar class and similar style is added for the other container)*

This moves the container and adds a transition effect to allow the smooth moving of the container to it's position at 0px from the right, and also adds a small delay, perhaps to allow content to be loaded fully in the two containers.

I assume you have knowledge of javascript/jquery enough to perform the task of swapping content and adding/removing classes from an element, so I won't go into loads of detail. If you need me to I can write the script and HTML to go with that code too.

Comment: Thanks Adam, I'll give it a go a bit later. With regards to the content swapping. What would be the most efficient way of getting new content into the divs? I'd like to give it a go myself but if you can point me in the right direction that would be awesome.

Comment: Well if you have it saved in a database for ease of updating etc, then I would do an AJAX call to a PHP document to load the content from that database. You could also do AJAX calls to HTML documents to load the content if you wanted to do it that way.

jQuery's html() and ajax() methods would probably help, or if you wanted to load the content immediately, save it all inside a JavaScript object in that script. You could then just update the object each time you needed to.

Comment: Ok I managed to get it working with 2 divs sliding from the left and right respectively. although I used % for their widths, however on changing the screen size, its giving me some issues with regards to them scaling correctly. It seems its the absolute positioning that is causing the problem. Would you have any suggestions on a fix?

Comment: If they are inside of a container, then making that container have position: relative would be good to ensure it gets all its parent information from that container. If you can create a jsfiddle of the current set up, I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: Hey Adam, I managed to get it working. Thanks so much for your help